# Removing elements of ArrayList and put at the end of the list

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist, java-8

I was trying to remove three elements from the ArrayList and put them an the end.

I want this output:

```
d
e
f
a
b
c
```

Here is my code:

```java
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

list.add("a");
list.add("b");
list.add("c");
list.add("d");
list.add("e");
list.add("f");

for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {

    String a = list.get(i);
        
    if (i < 3) {
        list.remove(i);
        list.add(list.size(), a);
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
b
d
f
a
c
e
```

If I do:

```java
for (int i = list.size()-1; i >=0 ; i--) {
        
    String a = list.get(i);
                
    if (i < 3) {
        list.remove(a);
        list.add(list.size(), a);
    } 
}
```

The output is:

```
d
e
f
c
b
a
```

I generally understand why I get these results, but I don't know how to solve it.

I tried this, but I didn't work:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {

    String a = list.get(i);

    if (i < 3) {
        list.remove(i);
        list.add(list.size(), a);
        i--;
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: This looks like Java. You should [edit] and add the [tag:java] tag. Also, the code snippet feature is for Javascript.

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) { list.add(list.remove(0)); }`

Comment: Thank you Johny, it worked :)

Comment: @JohnnyMopp that should be an answer! : )

Comment: `Collections.rotate(list, -3);`

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
int remove = 3; /* number of elements to remove */

list.add("a");
list.add("b");
list.add("c");
list.add("d");
list.add("e");
list.add("f");

for (int i = 0; i < remove; i++) {
  list.add(list.remove(0));
}
/* print */
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list.toArray()));
```